# How to run a HTML file inside another

Tags: html

Can I do this so that I can run my web app within its website?

The app does not require webkit.

Will it require Javascript?

Comment: `iframe` can be a good option for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)

> The HTML iframe Element (or HTML inline frame element) represents a nested browsing context, effectively embedding another HTML page into the current page.

With iframes you can embed a web page inside another, so I think it will suit your needs.

Example:

```
<iframe src="a_web_page.html" width="300" height="300" style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <!-- The following is displayed if the browser doesn't 
         support iFrames (unlikely scenario nowadays). -->
    <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

The web page inside the iframe is in a separate context from the "host" page (the one including the iframe). Your JavaScript code should run okay inside the iframe.

Comment: How to align iframe in center? `align-self: center;` is not working.

Comment: You could assign a CSS class to the iframe element, or use the style attribute. Centering depends on where the iframe is being contained.

Comment: For example, inside a div with a specific width, you could use CSS and tell the iframe: margin-left:auto; margin-right: auto;

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what for you is diffrent between web app and website, but I think that `iframe` could be a solution for you.